# Как автоматизировать работу с FIBPlus?

Tags: firebird, delphi-xe, fibplus

Info: DelphiXE, FIBPlus(Fast InterBase Plus) - компоненты для работы с Firebird, ну и база данных Firebird.

Может я просто чего-то не знаю... Оно заставляет меня делать так:

```
var tfDataSet: TFIBDataSet //просто для информации, на самом деле он лежит на форме

  tfDataSet.AutoUpdateOptions.UpdateTableName := AnsiUpperCase('BRANDS'); //имя таблицы
  tfDataSet.AutoUpdateOptions.KeyFields := 'BR_ID';                       //primary_key
  tfDataSet.AutoUpdateOptions.GeneratorName := 'GEN_BRANDS_ID';           //генератор для автонумерации (в базе тоже привязан к таблице)

  tfDataSet.GenerateSQLs;   //генерирует SQLs для UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT итд.
```

Если этого не сделать, то у меня данные в режиме readonly.

Хотя, по сути, всё есть в базе данных. Это действительно нужно самому запрашивать оттуда ручками и заполнять эти свойства или где-то есть какая-то галочка?

Answer (score 1):

В базе данных у Вас есть таблица `BRANDS`, но есть и десяток других таблиц. Нужно указывать с какой таблице мы работаем или компонент должен сам догадаться?

В базе данных есть генератор `GEN_BRANDS_ID`, но как компонент должен догадаться, что нужно использовать генератор и нужно использовать именно этот?

На самом деле использование метода `GenerateSQLs` не совсем правильно. Гораздо правильнее подключить `TFIBUpdateObject` и руками прописать все нужные запросы

Comment: Название таблицы по идеее должно браться автоматом из SelectSQL, да, умный компонент должен уметь это делать я считаю.
Какой генератор используется для данной таблицы прописано в системных таблицах базы данных, тоже компонент мог бы сам догадаться (Список генераторов он оттуда в combobox таки сам вытаскивает для выбора!). А на счёт UpdateObject пойду почитаю, спасибо.

Comment: @Isaev В `SelectSQL` у Вас может быть джойн, вьюха или селективная процедура. Что ему брать? Какой генератор используется прописано только там где он используется. Обычно это `BEFORE INSERT` триггер, но далеко не всегда это так. Он может нигде не использоваться в надежде на то, что его дернет клиент перед вставкой. Вот список - да, можно подтянуть из системных таблиц. Что компонент и делает

Comment: просто такие вещи, как Update-/Insert-/DeleteSQL обычно заполняются, если нужена какой-то особенная их функциональность (по опыту работы с PostgreSQL и компонентами PgDAC, да и не только в них), а стандартные запросы "по-умолчанию" работают без надобности их постоянно заполнять. Потому тут меня этот момент удивил.

Comment: @Isaev Я повторю свой вопрос В SelectSQL у Вас может быть джойн, вьюха или селективная процедура. Что ему брать?

Comment: ну есть стандартные случаи, которых большинство, когда там стоит просто имя таблицы и её можно попробовать вытащить. А ещё нет правил без исключений, если не нашёл что взять, можно попросить заполнить соответствующее поле. Что в таких случаях берёт PostgreSQL? Там этих вопросов не возникает, если это вьюха и там нет вычисляемых полей, апдейт работает на автомате без ввода UpdateSQL. Потому я и думал, что это везде так должно быть и я просто не знаю, как в этом компоненте этот момент активировать

Comment: у меня просто в проекте много таблиц, класть на форму для каждой DataSet, да и править программу, если создаётся новая тоже не хорошо. Потому мне нужно это сделать динамически, а через тот же TFIBUpdateObject снова нужно всё вручную прописывать

Comment: @Isaev у самого в программе используется такой подход: есть отдельная таблица с полями `table_name`, `select_sql`, `refresh_sql`, `insert_sql`, `update_sql`, `delete_sql`. Программа обращается к этой таблице и по значению `table_name` заполняет в DataSet все нужные поля